# Text messaging application disappeared

Tags: applications, sms

I have Samsung S Duos Ice cream Sand witch(4.1.2) loaded in it.I can't see my Text messaging app and also the icon in my phone for past two days.I am unable to get new messages also.I did not hide the application.Since it is one of the system application you can't uninstall.Is it any problem in the operating system to hide Messaging ?

Comment: Did you check your app drawer? Perhaps you have just accidentally deleted the shortcut from your home screen.

Comment: Also if for some reason it is not in the app drawer look in the system list of apps (Settings -> Apps -> All ->Name of Message App)